# Capture Window Messages (WM) in WinForms Designer using WndProc

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wndproc, windows-messages

I am writing a custom control in .NET Windows Forms. Consider the following code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    switch(m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // Yes, it's defined correctly.
            MessageBox.Show("Left Button Down");
            break;
    }
}
```

It works when running, but I need it to work in the designer. How can I achieve this?

**NOTE:**

I guess someone might say that "*You can't detect clicks in the designer because the design surface captures them and processes them as part of the design process*"

...Take for example the `TabControl`. When you add a new tab, you can click to navigate through the tabs, and then click the tab's designable area to begin designing the tab page's content. How does that work?

Comment: I might have missed something here, but how would that work? Your program is not running while you're looking at the designer.

Comment: @Octopoid - Your code still runs even in design mode - certain messages are allowed through the WndProc loop, but as per my comment, I think clicks are handled before they reach the control itself. (see update)

Comment: Fair enough, I don't really use the designer very much - what happens when you move `base.WndProc(ref m);` to the end of the method, after you handle your event?

Comment: @Octopoid - nothing, same issue.

Comment: hmm, I was hoping that the base method was just resetting the message to none. I have just found this: `if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)` - doesn't instantly help, but I wonder if that is part of the puzzle towards implementing custom designer features. I have often wondered how the `TabControl` etc. did it's thing..

Comment: @Octopoid - I guess it's worth investigating, thanks. I've just added a logger to WndProc to tell me which messages it's parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, designer eats some of the messages. If you want all messages to be sent to the `Control`, you need to create a custom control designer and send them to the control.

Refer [ControlDesigner.WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.wndproc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class CustomDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        DefWndProc(ref m);//Passes message to the control.
    }
}
```

Then apply the `DesignerAttribute` to your custom control.

```
[Designer(typeof(CustomDesigner))]
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // Yes, it's defined correctly.
                MessageBox.Show("Left Button Down");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Drag your control to the `Form`, click on it. Now you should see the message box in designer also :)